# Regular expression to manipulate text file - Windows

Tags: regex, string, nant

I am having issues manipulating a text file to get my desired results.

For example, I have the following lines within a text file called `sprocs.txt` which was created from an svn diff, similar to this:

```
     M      https://localhost/svn/Repo/branches/projectA/sprocs/admin/foo.sql
     M      https://localhost/svn/Repo/branches/projectA/sprocs/foo2.sql
     M      https://localhost/svn/Repo/branches/projectA/sprocs/admin
     M      https://localhost/svn/Repo/branches/projectA/sprocs
```

I am trying to edit this file so that it keeps everything starting with `/sprocs`, but deletes each line that does not end in `.sql`. For example, the file above would return the following:

```
    /sprocs/admin/foo.sql 
    /sprocs/foo2.sql
```

BTW: I plan to have these commands be handled by nant. Any ideas anyone? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would do the job using pure NAnt:

```
<target name="go">
  <property
    name="file.path"
    value="C:\foo\sprocs.txt" />
  <foreach
    item="Line"
    in="${file.path}"
    property="line">
    <property
      name="MATCH"
      value="" />
    <regex
      pattern="(?'MATCH'/sprocs.*\.sql)$"
      input="${line}"
      failonerror="false" />
    <if test="${string::get-length(MATCH) > 0}">
      <echo message="match: ${MATCH}" />
      <!-- do whatever you want to do with your match -->
    </if>
  </foreach>
</target>
```

Not as elegant as [palako's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13773955/38029) but it also works.

Comment: Hey Chairmain - when you do an "<echo file="Database.txt" append="true" message="${MATCH}" verbose="true" /> " , is there anyway that this ${MATCH} can be sorted alphabetically during or prior the append.

Comment: There is no easy way that comes to my mind. You could concatenate the strings with a delimiter, pass it to a <script>, get an ordered concatenated string back and loop over it. Things are cumbersome in NAnt sometimes... if you're interested in this solution leave a comment

Comment: Thanks. I wouldnt want you to go through that. I am trying to write something in C# <script language="C#"> (Trying !! ) , but was thinking...Is there another Regex that can probably sort my 'sprocs.txt' first? This way once sproc.txt is sorted I can then proceed to do the {MATCH}. Do you think that can work?

Comment: I found a solution to my problem. I was able to use the powershell command and sort it before doing to {MATCH}. gc sprocs.txt | sort | get-unique > sprocs-new.txt   , thanks agian !

Answer (score 2):

```
 $ cat sprocs.txt | sed -n 's/.*\(\/sprocs\/.*\.sql$\)/\1/p'
/sprocs/admin/foo.sql
/sprocs/foo2.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

The following regex pattern should work for you, it will create a capturing group that will find anything starting with `/sprocs` and ending with `.sql`

`(/sprocs.*\.sql$)`

Be sure to enable the multi-line mode by passing it in the options for the nant regex otherwise this will not match properly.  I believe this is the **m** option as is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this regex but it seems to be giving me the same results ! Am I doing anything wrong? <loadfile file="${sprocs.diff.results}" property="file.content" /> <regex pattern="(/sprocs.*\.sql$)" input="${file.content}" options="Multiline" /> <echo file="${db.build.dir}\${sprocs.diff.results}" append="false" message="${file.content}" verbose="true" />

Comment: NAnt's regex task requires the pattern to contain one or more named grouping constructs